# How do I get from the shell to the actual OS?

Tags: command-line, software-installation

I just installed Ubuntu for the first time and have no idea how Linux works in general. I used the Windows Installer and after a reboot I end up in a shell (?) with commands and have no idea what to do. How do I enter the actual OS with GUI?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu did you install? how did you install it? What Windows version do you have? What do you see on the screen when you start up, be precise!

Comment: I used the Windows Installer on the Ubuntu Homepage, I think it installed 12.04. I'm on Windows 8.1. What I see is what I described, the shell which prompts me to enter commands.

Comment: It reads "BusyBox v1.18.5 (Ubuntu 1:1.18.5-1ubuntu4.1) built in shell (ash)"

Answer (score 0):

Windows installer is not recommended/supported  with windows 8: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer. You need to install with the normal procedure (and it could be a bit tricky due to the "safe boot" feature). There is a link in the aforementioned page, that reads "[learn more...](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)"

By the way, the graphic interface is a shell too ;-).

Comment: No I did something else, I accidently installed it on my external drive without noticing -__- I plugged it out, installed it on my ssd and now everything works again